# Inverse of modulo operator in Python

Tags: python, math

I’m trying to solve the following set of equations for `time` in Python:

```
position1 = (initial_position1 + (time * velocity1)) % 360
position2 = (initial_position2 + (time * velocity2)) % 360
```

There are two objects revolving around a center point in the same direction, with different speed, and with possibly different starting points (ie. their position at a given time). I’d like to know how much time does it take for the two objects to meet.

For this, I have this equation:

```
(initial_position1 + (time * velocity1)) % 360 == (initial_position2 + (time * velocity2)) % 360
```

But I cannot solve it for `time` as there is no inverse function for the `%` operator. Is there a known solution for this? If not, any advice would come in handy.

Comment: Consider their relative displacement and relative speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're trying to solve

```
x1 + t * v1 = x2 + t * v2
and 
x1 - x2 = 360 * n
```

this translates into

```
n = t / 360 * (v2 - v1)
or
t = n * 360 / (v2 - v1)
```

you know what `v2` and `v1` are so this is just a linear equation with integer solutions.  Find all points on that line where n is an integer and take smallest positive one.

Answer (score 2):

What about writing your own function for the inverse modulo?

```
def invmodp(a, p):
    for d in xrange(1, p):
        r = (d * a) % p
        if r == 1:
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('%d has no inverse mod %d' % (a, p))
    return d
```

Note that not all sets have an inverse modulo ...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. There are multiple potential starting values that come to the same result after a modulo operation. If you want to refer back to the original starting value, save a reference to it.

Comment: You are definitely right in the sense that there is no simple inverse modulo operation. But the fact that there are only integer possibilities for the integer division leads to the solution given by @piRSquared for all natural numbers n (adjusted for different starting positions and times).